# Access data from particular directory with less line of codes

Tags: python, directory, path

Assume, I have a csv file `data.csv` located in the following directory `'C:\\Users\\rp603\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Basics\\tutorials\\Revision\\datasets'`. Using this code, I can access my csv file:

```
## read the csv file from a particular folder
import pandas as pd
import glob
files = glob.glob(r"C:\\Users\\rp603\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Basics\\tutorials\\Revision\\datasets*.csv")

df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in files:
    csv = pd.read_csv(f)
    df = df.append(csv)
```

But as you can see the `csv` file path is long. So, is there is any way to do the same operation where I can reduce the path location of my data as well as codes line.

Comment: Put it on a constants.py file and import the constant name.

Comment: You cannot reduce the path. Store the path in a variable and use it inside ```glob()```.

Comment: Any example of how to do this?

Comment: ```dirs_path = C:\\Users\\rp603\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Python Scripts\\Basics\\tutorials\\Revision\\datasets```. Use it in glob - ```glob.glob(dirs_path)```.

Answer (score 0):

use the "dot" notation for a relative path (it does not depend on the programming language)

```
# example for a "shorter" version of the path
import os

my_current_position = '.' # where you launch the program
files = '' # from above

print(os.path.relpath(files, my_current_position)
```

**Remark** `relpath` is order sensitive

You can use a context manager to open the file, not shorter but more elegant

```
with open(file, 'r') as fd:
    data_table = pd.read_csv(fd)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your script in the same directory as the datasets, you can simply do:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob("datasets*.csv")
```

Comment: If that is the case, I don't need these codes anymore. Because, I can read file directly using 'df=pd.read_csv('data.csv')'.  My datasets are in a different folders and the main script is in another folder (see my code)

Comment: You would still need to use `glob` right?

Comment: Nah. If I keep my datasets and script in the same location why do I need to use glob. I can directly read the file. I used 'glob' if the main script and datasets are in a different locations.